# C++ eclipse multithread error

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading

It's my first time to debug c++ multi thread program under Eclipse and can't solve the following error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void* say_hello(void* args)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        int ret = pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, say_hello, NULL);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
           cout << "pthread_create error: error_code=" << ret << endl;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The console log is:

```
21:50:36 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project thread1 ****
> make all  Building file: ../src/thread1.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
> g++ -Ipthread -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP
> -MF"src/thread1.d" -MT"src/thread1.d" -o "src/thread1.o" "../src/thread1.cpp" ../src/thread1.cpp: In function ‘void*
> say_hello(void*)’: ../src/thread1.cpp:10:1: warning: no return
> statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]  }  ^
> Finished building: ../src/thread1.cpp   Building target: thread1
> Invoking: GCC C++ Linker g++  -o "thread1"  ./src/thread1.o  
> -lpthread Finished building target: thread1  
> 
> 21:50:37 Build Finished (took 545ms)
```

Can someone point out where my mistake is? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You declare `say_hello` to return something (of type `void*`) but you don't actually return anything.

Comment: I dont see an error, but the warning is rather clear, isnt it?

Comment: Do you have to use `pthread`?  If you're using C++11 or newer you can use `std::thread` which actually works with the type system and IMHO is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread-entry function is declared to return a void* but you did not write a return statement.

```
void* say_hello(void* args)
```

I think a quick fix for this (maybe not the cleanest way) is to add the following return after your cout.

```
void* say_hello(void* args)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}
```

As mentioned above another way would be to go with c++11 threads